# Why is the app on my Admob account showing a default icon?

Tags: hyperlink, icons, admob, google-ads-api

[image]

Why is this one particular app on my Admob account showing a default icon, unlike my other apps, which have never done this before? Everything seems to be working fine for the app though on the Admob side of things (it shows no info in the pic above, but I know it works, because money has come in since then). I mean, I can collect money from the ads and everything, but for some reason it's just showing a default icon.

[Important Note: Also, I tried to create an Adwords app install campaign for the app in question, but the edit part where it actually shows you a visual example of the ad campaign before saving, wouldn't display itself (it just keep loading, but at the same time, it allowed me to go through the complete ad creation process successfully). I'm worried now about if my Adwords ads are even going to show up on user's phones, or will it do the same thing it did with me.]

Basically, how come there's a Admob (successfully linked) app icon problem, and why didn't the Adwords visual example of the ad load while editing?

Thanks in advance,
A Man, With A Question

Comment: same problem here, have you found the solution? A interesting thing is, my problematic app is also a countdown app, does for some reason Admob not like countdown app?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to App
2. Select the app you want to show icon
3. App Settings
4. See App name & store link
5. Click on Pencil icon
   [image: image screenshot]
6. Link your app with Google Play
7. Now enter your app name, app ID or developer name > Search and then click on Search button, icon will be link your app.
   [image: image screenshot 2]